# Nginx Wildcard SSL with Wordpress Multisite Subdomains

Tags: multisite, rewrite-rules, subdomains, ssl, nginx

I have a wildcard certificate that secures *.example.com and I need to strip out the canonical www for all requests made for subdomains, eg:
www.subdomain1.example.com => subdomain1.example.com

I reviewed this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323735/nginx-remove-www-and-respond-to-both

But the first server block they suggest:

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

does not work for www.subdomain.example.com

How can I catch and return a scheme for www.*.example.com ?

I reviewed another question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/249952/wildcard-vhosts-on-nginx
in which they use regular expression to match the server name, but I'm not sure how to apply this to my situation.

Here is my current setup:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/webroot;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    #subdomain multi site with wp in 'wp' subdir
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
    # Redirect wp-* files/folders
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) /wp/$2 last;

    # Redirect other php files
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) /wp/$2 last;
    }

    ...(etc)
}
```

Comment: hmmm is there a WP specific component you're unsure of? It might be better moving this to stackoverflow

Comment: You're right.  I drifted away from a WP-specific issue in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *regular expressions* in the `server_name` directive, but wildcard names (e.g. `*.example.com`) take precedence. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;
    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<name>(.+\.)?example\.com)$;
    return 301 https://$name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name ~^www\.(?<name>(.+\.)?example\.com)$;
    return 301 https://$name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    ...
}
```

The first `server` block matches `http` requests to any subdomain, and redirects to the non-www variant using `https`.

The second `server` block matches `https` requests to subdomains which begin with `www.` and redirects to the non-www variant.

The third `server` block does not need a `server_name` directive (as it is the default server) and handles all `https` requests to the main domain and non-www subdomains.

Comment: Thank you very much.  And the document was instructive as well - it says
A special wildcard name in the form “.example.org” can be used to match both the exact name “example.org” and the wildcard name “*.example.org”. 

But I'm not sure if their illustration of *.example.org implies an infinite number of prepended, dot-separated characters or not.  I may play around with this because of the rare edge case where you have https : // www.subdomain.example.com which still chokes with the regex you provided, and for which I am very grateful! :)

Comment: The `*` represents one or more subdomain prefixes. Using a wildcard name will break all of regular expression domains it matches.